# ADB shell change camera mode

Tags: adb, samsung-galaxy-s, shell, 8.0-oreo

I am playing around with the ADB shell to control a Samsung Galaxy S9 remotely.
I can do most of the things I wanted to but I struggle finding a way to switch / toggle the camera modes.

I searched everywhere and found very little information about this. I only found how to switch between front or back facing camera but I want to be able to select my slow motion mode.

Maybe I am not looking at the right place...

Does anyone have an idea how could I do this?

Any help is very much appreciated

thank you

Comment: Try using `input` to simulate taps on the screen.

Comment: The only relevant input is to swipe to change mode but even swiping for some reasons in the camera app doesn't work. But swiping works on the home screen ><